# How to set the version of my project?

Tags: composer-php

How do I set the version and stability of my composer project?

I assumed this would be done in the `composer.json` file, but none of the [popular frameworks](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/composer.json) seem to have anything in there indicating the version of the current project, just their dependencies. How do I set it?

Comment: What do you mean by version of your composer project?

Comment: @admdrew I don't know how else to explain that. In my composer.json I have things like `"require": { "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0" }`. Where does "4.0" come from? How does composer know what version phpunit is at?

Comment: That refers to a specific version of a required package. The `4.0` comes from picking that version of `phpunit/phpunit` (technically `~4.0` means versions greater than/equal to `4.0` but less than `5.0`), something that's up to you when you define the package requirements for your project.

Comment: @admdrew I don't think you're following. I'm creating my own project and I want to know how I specify the version of *my* project. PhpUnit was able to specify the version of their project, but I don't know how.

Comment: Yes, I understand now. [Packagist](https://packagist.org/about) also has information on versioning packages added there. I was thrown off by the reference `composer.json`, which isn't included in *your* packages.

Comment: @admdrew It isn't? I thought it was mandatory to have a composer.json to publish a package. I thought that's where all the info came from? What's the point of having a name/description/license/authors then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation is buried under a section called ["tags"](https://getcomposer.org/doc/02-libraries.md#tags).

Basically, the preferred method of adding versions is by creating a VCS tag that "looks" like a version. Composer will read these tags and determine the version based on that.

Comment: I guess unfortunately it doesn't offer any convenience tool for applying the version to the `composer.json` file during builds if you don't want VCS handling it.